# AVL Tree join operation Algorithm or Pseudocode in lg(N) time

Tags: java, algorithm, join, avl-tree

Last couple of days working on AVL Trees. I could not find any good Pseudocode that works in log(N) time. I want to avoid (if possible) the procedure of traversing a tree and add each node to other One.

Comment: How do you define the "Tree join" operation?

Comment: Here you'll find a c# implementation of concat. https://code.google.com/archive/p/self-balancing-avl-tree/source/default/source with explanation about the O-times as well

Comment: two avl tree will be provided to a method and it will return a new AVL tree @amit

Comment: @optimus_Prime any trees? No knowledge about elements, nothing like "all elements in one tree are larger than all elements in 2nd tree?" This is similar to `merge` (from merge sort), I doubt it can be done in sub linear time

Comment: yes amit, any tree. that means kind or state of two AVL Tree. my each  node has its rank and size(numberOfChild) property. can these help anyway to lead in sub linear time? i have done rank and size in log(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in sublinear time.

Proof:

Assume you could merge two avl trees in `f(n)` time, which is sublinear, we propose the following merge sort variation to create a sorted AVL tree, from a list of unsorted elements:

```
mergeSort(arr,l,r):
    if (r-l < 2):
          return new AVLTree(arr[l])
    mid = l + (r-l)/2
    T1 = mergeSort(arr,l,mid)
    T2 = mergeSort(arr,mid+1,r)
    return merge(T1,T2)
```

This is basically a variation of mergesort, and correctness proof is inductive similar to the one of mergesort.

Complexity:

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + f(n)

Using [master theorem case 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_1) with `a=b=2`, and some `c<1` (because `f(n)` is sublinear):

Conditions for case apply because `c < 1 = log_2(2) = log_b(a)`, so we can find some `c` such that `f(n)` is in `O(n^c)`, for some `c<1`.

Then, the theorem tells us `T(n)` is in `Theta(n^(log_b(a)) = Theta(n)`.

But that means we have created a linear time sorting algorithm, and since such algorithm cannot exist, since sorting is `Omega(nlogn)`, we cannot have merge that runs in sublinear time.

QED

Comment: OK. convinced about time complexity. But i really need some good resource on this join operation. Algorithm, Pseudocode, working mechanism etc etc. :(  @amit